# Need to return only one cell based on the search

Tags: python, csv, transform

I am trying a maltego transform in python, what I need is to return only one cell based on this search

```
@staticmethod
   def get_names(search_person_name):
    matching_names = []
    with open("examplefile.csv") as f:
        for ln in f.readlines():
            person_name, data = ln.split(",", 1)
            if person_name.strip() == search_person_name.strip():
                matching_names.append(data.strip())
    return matching_names
```

the .csv file consists of the following columns:

```
person_name,data,streetaddress
```

I would like, based on the search criteria it would only return the cell **data**

*Not* the row including the **streetaddress column**

Any idea?

Comment: As a simplification, use the [`csv`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/csv.html) module rather than splitting on commas manually? That will also handle things like quoted columns for you...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The reason why your "data" value was "data,streetaddress" was because you set your split function to only perform 1 split.

```
person_name, data = ln.split(",", 1)
```

The second argument of the split() function sets the max number of splits. Since you set it at 1, it only split the first "," that it saw. Since the content of the file is "person_name,data,streetaddress", then the variables became:

```
person_name = person_name
data = data,streetaddress
```

The easiest fix, as mentioned by @TBaggins is to change that line into:

```
person_name, data, streetaddress = ln.split(",", 2)
```

This makes the 2 splits from the line and places those 3 values in their respective variables.

Answer (score 2):

Here's one approach:
Replace

```
    person_name, data = ln.split(",", 1)
```

with

```
    person_name, data, unwanted_column = ln.split(",", 2)
```

which creates an extra variable you never use, but serves the purpose of severing it from the data you want.